# Oracle: quote table name

Tags: sql, oracle

I may be blind, but I just can't explain why the query

```
SELECT "VALUE"  AS value 
FROM   "TEST_INT"  
WHERE  "ID" = 20;
```

works, but

```
SELECT "VALUE"  AS value 
FROM   "TEST_INT" AS "TTT" 
WHERE "ID" = 20;
```

does not.

My SQL Developer replies

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 19
```

Am I quoting the name of the table wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not the quoting, Oracle does not support using `AS` for a table alias. So you cannot use

```
FROM test_int AS ttt
```

you can only use

```
FROM test_int ttt  -- note the missing AS keyword
```

Btw: as your column and table names are uppercase anyway, there is no need to quote the names.